# wrong result with c++ code polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have been asked to write a program that have 3 classes one for the student , the second for the date and the last foe the address 
and I have to create an objet in the main from the class student that have all the atributes of class student beside  3 dates from the class date and the address from the class address 
so i wrote the code and i used  a function in the class date to make sure the the date is in the correct form m/d/y , also i used set and get function 
but the problem is when i compile the code the final result shows all the values as"1"

here is my code : // class date header :

```
#ifndef Date_H
#define Date_H

class Date
{
public:

Date( int , int  , int ); // default constructor

void setmonth(int &);
void setday(int &);
void setyear(int &);

int getmonth() const;
int getday() const;
int getyear() const;

void print() const;  // print date in month/day/year format

~Date();  // provided to confirm destruction order

private:
int month;  // 1-12
int day;    // 1-31 based on month
int year;   // any year

// utility function to test proper day for month and year
   int checkDay( int );
};
#endif
```

// class date source :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using std::cout ;
#include "Date.h"

// Constructor: Confirm proper value for month;
// call utility function checkDay to confirm proper
// value for day.
Date::Date( int mn, int dy, int yr )
{
  if (mn > 0 && mn <= 12 )      // validate the month
       month = mn ; 
   else {
 month = 1;
  cout << "Month " << mn << " invalid. Set to month 1.\n";
   }
   month = mn ;   // validate the month
   year  = yr;                      // should validate yr
   day   = checkDay( dy );           // validate the day   


   cout << "Date object constructor for date ";
   print();         
   cout << endl;
}


int Date::getmonth() const
{
return month;
}
int Date::getday() const 
{
return day;
}
int Date::getyear() const
{
return year;
}


void Date::setmonth(int &m)
{
month = m;
}
void Date::setday(int &d)
{
day = d;
}
void Date::setyear(int &y)
{
year = y;
}


// Print Date object in form  month/day/year
 void Date::print() const
   { cout <<&Date::getmonth << '/' << &Date::getday << '/' << &Date::getyear ; }

// Destructor: provided to confirm destruction order
Date::~Date()
{ 
cout << "Date object destructor for date ";
  print();
  cout << endl;
 }
```

// class Address header :

```
#ifndef ADDRESS_H
#define ADDRESS_H
#include <string>
using namespace std ; 

class Address
{
public:


Address(double, string  , string ,string ,double);// default constructor

double getbuilding_number() const;
string getstreet() const;
string getcity() const;
string getcountry() const;
double getcode() const;


void setbuilding_number(double &);
void setstreet(string &);
void setcity(string &);
void setcountry(string &);
void setcode(double &);

void print() const; 

~Address();  // provided to confirm destruction order

private:
 double building_number;
 string street;
 string city;
 string country;
 double code;
};
#endif
```

// class address source :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Address.h"
using namespace std;

// Constructor


 Address::Address( double b_n ,string st ,string ci ,string coun ,double cod )
{
building_number = b_n;
 street = st;
 city = ci;
 country = coun;
 code = cod;


 cout << "Date object constructor for Address ";
 print();         
 cout << endl;
}

 void Address::setbuilding_number(double &b_n)
{
building_number =b_n;
}
void Address::setstreet(string &st)
{
street = st;
}
void Address::setcity(string &ci)
{
city= ci;
}
void Address::setcountry(string &co)
{
country = co;
}
void Address::setcode(double &co)
{
code = co;
}

double Address::getbuilding_number() const
{
return building_number;
}
string Address::getstreet() const
{
return street;
}
string Address::getcity() const
{
return city;
}
string Address::getcountry() const
{
return country;
}
double Address::getcode() const
{
return code;
}


// Print Adress object  
void Address::print() const
 {
   cout <<" Student's building number is " << &Address::getbuilding_number << endl  
   << " Student's street is " << &Address::getstreet << endl
   << " Student's city is " << &Address::getcity << endl 
   << " city code  is " << &Address::getcode << endl 
   << " Student's country is " << &Address::getcountry << endl ;
 }

// Destructor: provided to confirm destruction order
Address::~Address()
{ 
cout << "Address object destructor for Address ";
print();
cout << endl;
}
```

//class student header :

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>
using namespace std ;
#include "Address.h"
#include "Date.h"
class Student
{
public:
                                 Student(string,string,string,string,string,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,double,string,string,string,double);

void setFirst_Name(string &);
void setLast_Name(string &);
void setPhone_Number(string &);
void setMobile_Number(string &);
void setBirth_Date(Date &);
void setCertificate_Date(Date &);
void setRegistration_Date(Date &);
void setSpecialization(string &);
void setStudent_Address(Address &);


string getFirst_Name() const;
string getLast_Name()const ;
string getPhone_Number() const;
string getMobile_Number() const;
Date getBirth_Date() const;
Date getCertificate_Date() const;
Date getRegistration_Date() const;
string getSpecialization() const;
Address getStudent_Address() const;

 void print()  const ;
 ~Student();  // provided to confirm destruction order

private:
string  First_Name;
string  Last_Name;
string  Phone_Number;
string  Mobile_Number;
Date    Birth_Date;
Date    Certificate_Date;
Date    Registration_Date;
string  Specialization ; 
Address Student_Address;
};
#endif
```

//class student source :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using std::cout ;
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student(string  F_Name , string  L_Name  , string  Ph_Number , string  Mob_Number ,string  Spec ,
                int B_Month , int B_Day , int B_year ,
                int C_Month , int C_Day , int C_year ,
                int R_Month , int R_Day , int R_year ,  
                double S_Building_Num  ,  string  S_Street , string  S_City  , string S_Country , double S_Code )
                :Birth_Date( B_Month, B_Day, B_year ),
                Certificate_Date( B_Month , B_Day, B_year ),
                Registration_Date(B_Month , B_Day, B_year ),
                Student_Address(S_Building_Num  , S_Street , S_City  , S_Country ,S_Code )
{
First_Name = F_Name ;         // copy F_Name into First_Name
Last_Name = L_Name ;          // copy L_Name into Last_Name
Phone_Number = Ph_Number ;    // copy Ph_Number into Phone_Number 
 Mobile_Number = Mob_Number ; // copy Mob_Number into Mobile_Number
 Specialization = Spec  ;     // copy Spec into Specialization 

 cout << "Student object constructor : " 
     << &Student::getFirst_Name << ' ' << &Student::getLast_Name << ' ' <<   &Student::getPhone_Number << ' ' <<  &Student::getMobile_Number  << ' ' << &Student::getSpecialization  <<  endl ; 
}

void  Student::setFirst_Name(string &fname)
{
    First_Name = fname ; 
}

void Student::setLast_Name(string &lname )
{
        Last_Name = lname ;
}

void Student::setPhone_Number(string &PN)
{
        Phone_Number = PN ;
}

void Student::setMobile_Number(string  &MN)
{
        Mobile_Number = MN ;
}

void Student::setBirth_Date(Date  &birth )
{
    Birth_Date = birth ;
}

void Student::setCertificate_Date(Date &cer)
{
    Certificate_Date = cer ;
}

void Student::setRegistration_Date(Date &rdate)
{
    Registration_Date = rdate ;
}

void Student::setSpecialization(string &spe)
{
    Specialization = spe ;
}

void Student::setStudent_Address(Address &s_address)
{
    Student_Address = s_address ; 
}

string Student::getFirst_Name()  const
{
    return First_Name ; 
}
string Student::getLast_Name()  const
{
    return Last_Name ;
}
string Student::getPhone_Number()  const
{
    return Phone_Number;
}
string Student::getMobile_Number()  const
{
    return Mobile_Number;
}
Date Student::getBirth_Date()   const
{ 
    return Birth_Date ;
}
Date Student::getCertificate_Date()  const
{
    return Certificate_Date;
}
Date Student::getRegistration_Date() const
{
    return Registration_Date;
}
string Student::getSpecialization() const
{
    return  Specialization ; 
}
Address Student::getStudent_Address()  const
{
    return Student_Address ;
}
void Student::print() const 
{ 
cout <<&Student::getFirst_Name << " , " << &Student::getLast_Name << "," << &Student::getPhone_Number << " , "  <<  &Student::getMobile_Number  <<    "\nBorn on : "  ;
Birth_Date.print() ;
cout << "The date of the Bakaloria Certificate is : " ;
Certificate_Date.print() ; 
cout << "The date of the Registration  is : " ;
Registration_Date.print() ;
cout << "Student's Specialization is : " << &Student::getSpecialization  << endl ;
cout << "Student's Address  is : " ;
Student_Address.print() ; 
cout << endl ; 
}

// Destructor: provided to confirm destruction order

Student::~Student()
{

cout << " Student object destructor : " 
 << First_Name << ' ' << Last_Name << ' ' << Phone_Number << ' ' <<  Mobile_Number  << ' ' << Specialization  <<  endl ; 
}
```

// the main function :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std ; 
#include "Student.h" 


int main () 

{

Student s("dana" , "fakhri" , "25186" , "0940200",  "ise" , 9, 9 ,1990, 9,15,2009 , 4,12,2011 , 6 , "AL-Jala2 street " , "Hamah" , "Syria" , +963 ) ;

cout << '\n'  ;

s.print() ; 

return 0 ; 

}
```

the problem is : 
[a link] (http://www.4shared.com/photo/ik6C5EZFce/pro.html)

Comment: Minimal example please. There's a lot of "noise" in there.

Comment: hers is a print screen in the link : [link](http://www.4shared.com/photo/ik6C5EZFce/pro.html)

Comment: i forgot to tag you :D @Borgleader

Comment: The example and expected values are in the `main()` function, although it is far from minimal ;-)

Comment: forgive me guys but my English is a little bit weak so i didn't understand what you are asking me very clearly :( 
what do you mean when you say " far from minimal "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your printing at the end of the constructor:

The use of `&` will get the address of the data (and here even of your memeber functions)  and not the data itself.

Correct it to:

```
cout << "Student object constructor : " 
     << Student::getFirst_Name() << ' ' << Student::getLast_Name() << ' ' <<   Student::getPhone_Number() << ' ' <<  Student::getMobile_Number()  << ' ' << Student::getSpecialization()  <<  endl ; 
}
```

Comment: but when i removed & and wrote it like the way you talk about the compiler is giving me this error :
    error C3867: 'Student::getLast_Name': function call missing argument list; use '&Student::getLast_Name' to create a pointer to member

Comment: and i know there is a problem in her but where ?? 
because it shouldn't ask me to put & , all the examples the i have seen about polymorphosims were not inىclude this " &class:: " !!!

Comment: The error maessage looks like you forgot to add `()` after `getLast_Name`

Comment: thanks aloooot ... really it was a silly mistake but it caused a lot of damage ...
but there is another problem why in the output there is a 3 time print for the same constructor ?? 
i made a print screen you can see it in this link : [link] (http://www.4shared.com/photo/KdTyrRXLce/problem_2.html)